# In Blogger, How Do I Make Links Underlined Only Inside Posts

Tags: html, css, blogger

I see there's this tag in Blogger:

```
a:link {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: $(link.color);
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: $(link.visited.color);
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
  color: $(link.hover.color);
}
```

But if I change `a:link` to `text-decoration:underline`, then EVERY link in the entire blog becomes underlined which is not what I intended. I just need links inside articles/posts to be underlined. Everything else stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target the links inside the posts using ***descendant selector***.

```
.post-body a:link {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

In the above code, replace `.post-body` with the ID/Class of the article/post. Most probably it is .post-body by default.

Comment: OK, that's cool. One step closer. But this also changed all post titles to underlined text. I just need it to change the links inside posts, not even the title. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Yup, done it already before I read the updated answer :P. Thanks man. That's awesome

Comment: Glad you did it before :D Welcome!